# C# equivilent to Java's java.awt.image.DataBuffer

Tags: c#, java, image, buffer

Here's my Java Code:

```
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;

public class B extends DataBuffer
{
  public float[][] a;
  public float[] b;

  public float[] a()
  {
    return this.b;
  }
}
```

Question is plain and simple.  What is the C# equivalent to java.awt.image.DataBuffer?

Or do I need to back up one level and find the equivalent to java.awt.image?

TIA,

KeithC

Comment: I read the Java documentation on `DataBuffer` and I cannot see what the purpose of it is. It seems to be an abstraction on top of arrays. In C# you can just use arrays, e.g. `int[]`, `float[]`, etc.

Comment: +1 lookslike you are right.. its just a collection of arrays called banks.. its extended to make Int Array , byte array.. etc.. i think Array class can do very much the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do some sort of image manipulation. You seem to need direct access to the pixel data for a bitmap because method calls would be too slow.

.NET provides [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) for this purpose. Here’s an example how you might use this:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
unsafe
{
    var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        var b = (byte*) data.Scan0 + y * data.Stride;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            var blue = b[4 * x];
            var green = b[4 * x + 1];
            var red = b[4 * x + 2];
            var alpha = b[4 * x + 3];

            // ... do whatever you want with these values ...
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
return bmp;
```

In order to use this, you need to enable *unsafe code* in your project. In the project properties, on the “Build” tab, enable the option *Allow unsafe code*.